# Why order_ids is an array instead of single orderId in checkout success action observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

After placing an order I want observer success event.Can any one clarify following one.

Is there any possiblity multiple orders ?

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has been ported directly from Magento 1, where it was always an array but also always with one item. It looks like this was built with the intention to allow multishipping (shipping to multiple addresses) within the onepage checkout, but it has never been done in Magento core.

However it's possible that custom checkout extensions create multiple orders, so if you build an extension for a wider audience, better expect the possibility of multiple order ids.

Comment: any way we can't do multiple orders, can you explain how an extension can create multiple orders,  i m not clear with the concept of multiple order

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any possiblity multiple orders,*->*`No`*. for a single order,it is only provide one order id.

In order get order id try use foreach loop

Comment: so why they are using array.i'm getting orderId by using order_ids[0].i fear that  it will change latter.

Comment: so there is no problem to use order_ids[0]?

Comment: why you does not use foreach loop..i throght i will better as it object

Comment: at present i'm checking like this   if (isset($orderIds[0])).

Comment: foreach always better

Answer (score 0):

When you look at

`Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface`

```
`public function dispatch($eventName, array $data = []);`
```

It accept a second argument as array that's why magento pass as array and **there are no possibility of multiple orders**.